# How to import CSV file into Cloud Bigtable via Cloud Dataflow with Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

The easiest way to describe what I'm doing is essentially to follow this tutorial: [Import a CSV file into a Cloud Bigtable table](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cbt-import-csv), but in the section where they start the Dataflow job, they use Java:

```
mvn package exec:exec \
    -DCsvImport \
    -Dbigtable.projectID=YOUR_PROJECT_ID \
    -Dbigtable.instanceID=YOUR_INSTANCE_ID \
    -Dbigtable.table="YOUR_TABLE_ID" \
    -DinputFile="YOUR_FILE" \
    -Dheaders="YOUR_HEADERS"
```

Is there a way to do this particular step in python?  The closest I could find was the `apache_beam.examples.wordcount` example [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python), but ultimately I'd like to see some code where I can add some customization into the Dataflow job using Python.

Answer (score 3):

There is [a connector for writing to Cloud Bigtable](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigtableio.html), which you can use as a starting point for importing CSV files.